# Using Excel's SUMIFS function with a date criteria

Tags: excel, sumifs

I have a data:

```
A         B      C
13524   2012-07  2
13524   2012-08  9
13524   2012-09  5
13524   2012-10  2
13524   2012-11  7
```

Now i would like to sum the values in `column C`, if date is greater than value specified in a cell:

```
  D         E       F
13524    2012-09
```

Above, in cell under `column F`, I write:

```
=SUMIFS($C:$C,$A:$A,D1,$B:$B,">="&E1)
```

which will give me the sum of values that have greater or equal to date than 2012-09, so the result should be `5+2+7 = 14`, but it returns 0. What is wrong above?

Comment: Are the dates in column B, actual dates or strings.

Comment: I replicated it, and it worked correctly using dates not string. The greater than function may not work with strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to convert the strings in your example to real dates, e.g. by using

```
=DATE(LEFT(B2;4);MID(B2;6;2);1)
```

to yield the first day in the respective month.

Then, you will need to change your cell `E1` to also have a date instead of string as value.

Comment: You could also do it with =DATEVALUE(B2&"-01")